# How to use Modulus relation to compare two quantities?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

Given, $|x| \neq x$

Options:

a) $x > -x$

b) $x < -x$

c) $x = -x$

d) Cannot be determined

My solution:
  If  $|x| \neq x$   then   $-x = x$  hence option c seems to be the answer.
  But the solution is option b.
  I'm not understanding the logic behind this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
$$
|x|\ne x \Rightarrow x<0\Rightarrow -x>0 \Rightarrow x<-x
$$